# JSON.parse Map want String get integer

Tags: json, dart

Dart is great, it's like, well, programming. Also the IDE is great.
I have encountered what appears to me to be a problem (for me) with the Dart
JSON.parse function.  The problem appears to me to be that if a string
is an integer, it creates an integer in the Map. This may not be desirable
because there could be situations where string fields contain numeric.
eg. an address that contains just the street number. Or, perhaps I am
simply doing something wrong.

The line of code that exposes the possible problem is :

```
String sId       = mAcctData['I_Id'];
```

I presume that there is a logical solution to this, and if so I would
appreciate being advised

```
httpSubmitAccountNrLoadEnd(HttpRequest httpReq) {
  String sResponse = null;
  if (httpReq.status != 200) {
    print('On Http Submit Account Nr. There was an error : status =        ${httpReq.status}');
  } else {
    print("On Return from Http Submit Account Nr. no error - status =   ${httpReq.status}");
    sResponse = httpReq.responseText;
  }

  print("Response From Submit Account Nr. = ${sResponse}"); // print the received raw     JSON text

  Map mAcctData = JSON.parse(sResponse);
  print ("Json data parsed to map");

  print ("Map 'S_Custname' = ${mAcctData['S_Custname']}");
  String sCustName = mAcctData['S_Custname'];

  print ("About to extract sId from Map data");
  String sId       = mAcctData['I_Id'];
  print ("sId has been extracted from Map data");

  String sAcctNr   = mAcctData['I_AcctNr'];
  String sAcctBal  = mAcctData['I_AcctBal'];
```

The following is the console output.
The line that shows the problem that I have is:

```
Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'sId'.
```

> ```
>  About to send http message
> On Return from Http Submit Account Nr. no error - status = 200
> Response From Submit Account Nr. = {"S_Custname":"James Bond","I_Id":1,"I_Acctnr":123456789,"I_AcctBal":63727272,"I_AvailBal":0}
> Json data parsed to map
> Map 'S_Custname' = James Bond
> ```

About to extract sId from Map data

Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'sId'.

Stack Trace: #0      httpSubmitAccountNrLoadEnd (http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/Brian/dart/transact01/transact01.dart:75:31)

## 1      submitAccountNr.submitAccountNr. (http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/Brian/dart/transact01/transact01.dart:33:59)

Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'sId'.
Stack Trace: #0      httpSubmitAccountNrLoadEnd (http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/Brian/dart/transact01/transact01.dart:75:31)

## 1      submitAccountNr.submitAccountNr. (http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/Brian/dart/transact01/transact01.dart:33:59)

Questions:

1. Is there a solution to this? (eg. force JSON.parse to create strings)
2. Is there a better way to handle this? (eg. extract data directly from the JSON string)

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in your `sResponse` `mAcctData['I_Id']` is really an `int` :

```json
{
  "S_Custname": "James Bond",
  "I_Id": 1,
  "I_Acctnr": 123456789,
  "I_AcctBal": 63727272,
  "I_AvailBal": 0
}
```

So if you want to get a `String` for `mAcctData['I_Id']` you can use [int.toString()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_core/int.html#toString) :

```dart
String sId = mAcctData['I_Id'].toString();
```

Comment: Ok, my bad. I thought that it was creating an integer from it because it was numeric data, rather than the fact that it is a numeric field from the representation in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn your integers into strings if you want them to be like that:

```json
{
    "S_Custname": "James Bond",
    "I_Id": "1",
    "I_Acctnr": "123456789",
    "I_AcctBal": "63727272",
    "I_AvailBal": "0"
}
```

Now it should work fine. Alternatively, use `.toString()` to convert the integers into strings.